# how to create editable combobox with list

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt5

I want to create an editable combobox in pyqt5 that when the user typs something, it gets the results from a list with names and puts it in the combobox.

So for example if the users types 'P', I want to add all the names from the list starting with P.
I have tried several things but without succes.
This is what I have so far

Thank you for helping me out, or put me on the right direction.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from testApp import Ui_MainWindow

names = ['Peter', 'Paul', 'Parker']

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.cboTestCombobox.editTextChanged.connect(lambda: self.getName(self.cboTestCombobox.currentText()))

    def getName(self, name):
        #self.cboTestCombobox.clear()
        if self.cboTestCombobox.currentText() != '':
            result = [i for i in names if name in i]
            self.cboTestCombobox.addItems(result)
        self.cboTestCombobox.showPopup()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like you want is a QCompleter:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        names = ["Peter", "Paul", "Parker"]

        le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(
            names, self, caseSensitivity=QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive
        )
        le.setCompleter(completer)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(le)
        lay.addStretch()

        self.resize(320, 120)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Good point to use the completer class. I should change to that instead of using combobox. Thank you!